# How do I take in more than just a single word using text files

Tags: c++, input, text-files

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //ifstream for input from files to program
    //ofstream for output to file
    string str;

    ofstream PI_file("test.txt");
    PI_file <<"Has this reached the file";
    PI_file.close();

    ifstream TO_file("test.txt");
    TO_file >> str;

    cout << str;
}
```

When I output str, it just prints "Has" so only the first word from file TO_file has reached str. Why is this? Also, how can I fix it so I can take in the whole file?

Also, another question I had was that if I wanted to use a for loop to loop through each letter or word in a string, I could use:

```
for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++)
```

But if I wanted to loop through a file until I reach the last word or letter in the file, how could I do this? Could I use "test.txt".length() or maybe TO_file.length()? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried indenting the code to make it readable

Comment: This is how [stream input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) works. If you want the whole line, use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: For larger quantities there is `std::istream::read` in which you can specify the amount to read.

Comment: @Ed Heal I have indented the code for you so you can read it

Comment: @OlafDietsche I have tried using getline() but it has given me an error saying "expected ';' before 'getline' ". Here is my attempt of using getline() in replace for line TO_file >> str; :

Comment: TO_file getline(cin, str);

Comment: @Thomas Matthews ok thanks I can have a look at that.

Comment: The correct usage is `std::getline(TO_file, str);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to correct you, the entire line that you sent to test.txt has reached there successfully. I just tested your code. While it only outputs *Has*, the entire line *Has this reached the file* is actually in the test.txt.

The problem in your code is how you read the text file. When you do the following line,

```
    TO_file >> str;
```

You forget that str is a variable of type string. If you ever try accepting input for a string variable, the compiler will only accept what exists before a space character, just like there is one in your line after the word **Has**. For example,

```
     string s;
     cin >> s;
```

If you input "Hello there!", The compiler will only store the first word (i.e Hello) in the variable s. Likewise in your function, only the first word of your line is transferred to the **str** variable.

You will have to rewrite your code for reading test.txt. I will provide a sample template from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) below:

```
      string line; // You store the string sentence in this variable
      ifstream myfile ("example.txt"); // You open the file in read mode
      if (myfile.is_open()) // If the file is successfully accessed and opened, then:
      {
        while (getline (myfile,line)) // Get every line from the file until you reach end of file
        {
          cout << line << '\n'; // Here you do whatever you want to do with the line from the file
        }
        myfile.close(); // Close the file at the end
      }

      else cout << "Unable to open file"; // If the file cannot open, print error message
```

The mistake of your code is fixed in the condition of the while-loop:

```
        getline (myfile,line)
```

Rather than simple getting the first word, you can get the entire line in a file (Just one line, not the entire text file) and output it. It should be pretty straightforward from here on. Good luck!

Comment: Why do you take line as the length in getline()

Comment: Oh ok thanks but by putting getline (myfile,line) in the while loop condition, how is it actually getting the line even though it is a condition for the while loop

Comment: I understand why you have taken length as the length in getline now but how does the program now to stop reading in lines from the file once it has read the whole file? Also, wouldn't the whole file be one getline because (I think) getline takes in input until an enter character is pressed and as this is a file, enter isn't going to be pressed.

Comment: @AmeenIzhac `std::getline()` returns a reference to the stream it was passed; for `getline(myfile, line)`, for example, it returns `myfile`.  Then, since `while` expects a boolean value, `myfile` is converted to a boolean value by `myfile.operator bool()`.  `basic_istream::operator bool()` returns `false` if anything went wrong, or `true` otherwise.  So, in effect, `while (getline(myfile, line))` checks whether `getline()` was able to successfully get a line from `myfile`.

Comment: (By `basic_istream::operator bool()`, I mean `basic_ios::operator bool()`.  My mistake.  Either way, `operator bool()` is inherited by all standard stream objects.)

Comment: This is considered one of the idiomatic C++ input loops, along with `while (myfile >> line)`.  Generally speaking, `while (obtain resource)` and `if (obtain resource)` are idiomatic ways of both obtaining a resource and verifying that it's valid before using it, following the "good resource is `true`, bad resource is `false`" mindset common to both C and C++.  A similar construct can be used to obtain and verify pointers; for any pointer `ptr`, it would look like `if (ptr = getPointer())` (where `getPointer()` returns a null pointer on failure).

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question @AmeenIzhac. when we say getline( myFile, line), it means the same thing as getline(cin, line) except cin is used in a non-file operation. As for how it works, I completely agree with Justin Time for his clear explaination.

Comment: Regarding your question about how it knows the end of the file, every time you use getline() in the while loop, a "cursor" in the text file moves along the lines in the file, invisible to the user. Its like the blinking cursor in a text file at the point where you are typing. That's why it moves on to the next line; getline() reads a line in the file, passes it to the program, and then moves the cursorto the next line of this .txt file. It knows it is at the end of the file because when it is, getline() as a function becomes impossible to run.

Comment: Try seeing it as when the function runs, it is true, and as soon as it fails to run (in this case because it is at the end of the line), it returns false. This change in the Boolean value makes the condition false, and as a result, the while loop terminates. This style of the while loop is very useful and has a lot of other applications. Hope this helps. Sorry for 3 comments; there is a character limit for the comments.

Comment: Ok thanks to both of you @Newbie to Programming and Justin Time I understand it now